# Working with password in Hibernate (for standalone applications)

Tags: mysql, spring, swing, hibernate, password-encryption

I'm looking for best practices around how to deal with password fields in my Java standalone application (Netbeans+Spring+Hibernate+MySQL database+Swing).

1) I've created a table with a password column.... so, which data type must be this column?
2) Which kind of algorythms for SALTing passwords do you recomend to follow and implement on my app?
3) Do you recommend saving password as a plain-text or after being transformed according with the algorythm?
4) Sample codes of all this process

I hope we can help many other developers who must deal with Spring for standalone apps and around the tasks with Hibernate on this kind of questions.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You should never store the password as a plain text in your application. Its not recommended for a highly secured application. You can use the PasswordEncoder provided by the Spring Framework itself to store the password in an encoded format to the database. You need to do following settings in your applocationContext.xml file.

```
<security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider >
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
              users-by-username-query="
              select  emailid username,password,'true' enabled from tbl_LoginDetails
              where emailid=?"
             authorities-by-username-query="
             select a.emailid username,b.authority from tbl_LoginDetails a,tbl_UserRoles b
            where a.userId=b.userId
            and a.emailid=?"/>
            <security:password-encoder  ref="passwordEncoder">
            </security:password-encoder>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>


    <bean name="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"></bean>
```

At the time of user registration you need to encode the password yourself in the controller before storing in the database with the class `ShaPasswordEncoder`.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: 1) I see two SQL queries, these must be adapted depending on my database? (2) do you have an example in Java about how can I set the password encoded? (3) In mysql database the password field which data type can I set to it? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You can set the password field is of datatype varchar. In java you just need to access the method of class *ShaPasswordEncoder*. Yes the queries are dependent on your database.

Comment: (1) The ShaPasswordEncoder class instance can work independently from the appconfiguration.xml, I mean: the config's surrounded by     </security:authentication-manager> is necesary to  do? (2) Why do I need to set my ShaPasEncoder class as a bean?

Comment: (3) I have two scenarios: (1.1) when I register my user for first time, and (1.2) when I start a new session in my system with a login window right? The (1.1) and (1.1) scenarios I can deal with ShaPassEncoder class. XML configuration why it is important?

Comment: (1) The configuration is necessary to do that is surrounded by </security:authentication-manager> because that is responsible to convert the user password to encoded form and then match that with the encoded password in database with the query defined there.

Comment: (2) You have to define it as bean because in the </security:authentication-manager> configuration you are referencing that bean as the password-encoder mechanism.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. (1) Do I have to create in my database exactly the tables and columns as figured in users-by-username-query and authorities-by-username-query tagas? (2) Once I have done the configs tags, and from the Java sive...  what do I have to do in my public static void main() method in order to enable the automatic authentication?

Comment: Hi again. (1) I have my appcontext.xml with both Spring and SpringSecur configs. But when I run my standalone app it shows me the message: "No authentication manager set. Reauthentication of users when changing passwords will not be performed". After that I have my Java swing frame with user and password textboxes... once i have completed that data I press Login.... my question is: what another command do I have to set in order to authenticate my user automatically? or is there another steps from Java side?